# Export an 3000x2512 complex double to tiff file

Tags: matlab, matrix, tiff, geotiff

I created a 3000x2512 complex double matrix where each cell represent a value. I want to export this matrix to a tif file so I can do further image processing in another application (Arcmap).
What's the best way to do that ?

Please note, i'm not a matlab user usually.
I tried to use  (I = the matrix):

```
imwrite(I, 'my_graphics_file.tif','tif');
```

but the output is just a blank tif file. 
I know the matrix works because when I try to display it as a figure, I can view it successfully.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can not expect to get a tiff file from a **complex** matrix. Maybe you want to create two images, one for the real part:

```
imwrite(real(I), 'my_graphics_file_real.tif','tif');
```

and one for the imaginary part

```
imwrite(imag(I), 'my_graphics_file_imag.tif','tif');
```

Or alternatively for absolute value and phase. Also be aware that imwrite with double matrix input assumes the value to be within [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in MATLAB. While LibTIFF supports double complex data type, MATLAB doesn't seem to have implemented that.

It is indicated [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) (under SampleFormat
) that 'Void, ComplexInt, and ComplexIEEEFP are not supported.' (Complex IEEEFP refers to complex IEEE floating point data)